# Reading data with bash, "for i in" combined with while

Tags: bash

I've the following challenge. I'm trying to read some data from a Datalogger with WebIF, the script basically runs as expected. But I'ld like to add a check using a while loop. And now I'm stuck at that "for i in & while" combo...

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PASSWD=blah
    OUTFILE=$(date +%d).csv
    OUTPATH=$(date +%Y/%m/)
    LOGPATH="./test/log/"
    BASEPATH="./test/"
    DEVICENAME=wc-s0
    NETWORK=somewhere.lan
    CURLPARA="-silent --connect-timeout 5"
    TRYS=3

    for i in {0..5};
    do
        TIME="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")";
        while [[ $TRYS -ne 0 ]] ; do
             VALUE=$(curl $CURLPARA "http://"$DEVICENAME"."$NETWORK"/counter?PW="$PASSWD"&"|grep counter|cut -sd ";" -f $(( i+2 ))|sed 's#kWh##g'|sed 's#kVARh##g'|sed 's#,#.#g');
        rc=$?
        if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]] ; then
            TRYS=1
        fi
        ((TRYS = TRYS - 1))
        done

        if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Read $DEVICENAME input"$i"."
        else
        echo "Timeout while reading $DEVICENAME input"$i"."
        fi
        echo "$VALUE"
        echo -n "$DEVICENAME input"$i"; "
        echo "$TIME; "
done
```

The out put is as follow's:

```
Read wc-s0 input0. 
wc-s0 input0; 2012-09-15 16:58:34;  
Read wc-s0 input1. 
wc-s0 input1; 2012-09-15 16:58:38;
Read wc-s0 input2. 
wc-s0 input2; 2012-09-15 16:58:38;
Read wc-s0 input3.
wc-s0 input3; 2012-09-15 16:58:38;
Read wc-s0 input4.
wc-s0 input4; 2012-09-15 16:58:38;
Read wc-s0 input5.
wc-s0 input5; 2012-09-15 16:58:38;
```

The "0.560" is a $VALUE but I'ld expect it to be like this:

```
Read wc-s0 input0.
wc-s0 input0; 2012-09-15 15:58:36; 0.560  
Read wc-s0 input1.
wc-s0 input1; 2012-09-15 15:58:37; "$VALUE2"
```

But I can't get it to print the data this way...

Hope one of you has a hint!

Comment: Why don't you print all your data in a single `echo` command?

Comment: `bash` can do integer math within `$(( ))`, so `$(echo "$i+2" | bc)` could be written `$(( i+2 ))` (variable markers (`$`) are implicit within math expansion).

Comment: I'm not sure how that could be the output.  According to your code, it should be printing either `Read device inputX` or `Timeout while reading...` on each line.  Are you sure that you are posting the actual code and output?

Comment: Yes I didn't have the actual version, because I stripped out some code to not post to much... I edited the code above so it's as it should be.

Comment: The thing is that I don't get the $VALUE printed in my output. I added the while loop to ensure it keeps trying up to three times if the first curl run doesn't return a value... So thank's for all your optimization's, I'm still learning and so am greateful for any hint! But I need to get a solution get the value printed. What I'm trying to accomplish is to read data from a meter and write it to a CSV. And for testing I want it to be on the console...

Comment: Yes, the odd thing is that there isn't even a blank line where the value should be.  If this really is the code that is producing that output, then the only way I could see that happening is if VALUE contained some special characters which moved the cursor up one line.

Comment: VALUE should contain something like 0 or 0.1 or more... But if curl runs into timeout it would contain nothing... So how can I ensure that?

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing the line this way:

```
    echo "$DEVICENAME input"$i"; $TIME; $VALUE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. without testing myself, just on the eye

1) Instead of seq you can use syntax {1..100} or {m...q} in curly brackets, without external quotes, especially with FOR loops. I just tried, seq generates newline with each step output.

2) Always put () with "if"

3) What's TRYS variable used for ? Anyway, using it inside check expression, use quotes ALWAYS, because if for some reason TRYS value will be empty, this will generate bad expression, so [[ "$TRYS" -ne 0 ]] better than [[ $TRYS -ne 0 ]]

4) On my eye, I wouldn't be surprised that curl call generates line-between numbers output, or adds newlines to VALUE contents. Consider using stream redirections like 2>&1 or 2>/dev/null etc, or clearing out non-alphanumeric characters from curl output

5) Regarding newlines, instead of duplicating echoes, try something like echo -en "aaa\nbbb\n"

6) For increment/decrement variables in bash, try $((TRYS++)) or $((--TRYS)) syntaxl

Let me know if it helped :)

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ seq 0 5
0
1
2
3
4
5
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ for i in {0..5} ; do echo -n $i; done ; echo
012345
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ for i in {0..5} ; do echo -n "$i "; done ; echo ;
0 1 2 3 4 5 
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

Comment: What do you mean by () in `if`? In `bash`, you certainly don't need a subshell to run a command in `if` in the normal case (maybe you are mixing up `csh` syntax?)